# Running pod install on OSX Yosemite

Tags: ios, cocoapods, osx-yosemite

I just updated to the latest seed and ran cocoapods on one of my projects. Everytime I run it I get the following error:

[!] An error occurred while performing `git pull` on repo `lcl`.
[!] /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only

fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.

I've tried reinstalling cocoapods, setting up the master repo and still no luck..

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you should give more details about your issue, like pods inside your cocoapods file, have you tried cloning the report by hand?, or somethings like that, with the information you give is almost impossible to answer your question, unless someone faced the same problem

Comment: CocoaPods has been giving me a series of problems on Yosemite beta.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? `pod install --verbose`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably means you have something stopping you from doing a `git pull` in the specs repository in `~/.cocoapods/repos/master`. The easiest way to deal with this is just remove it:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
pod setup
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

1. Open Xcode 6
2. Open Preferences
3. Click the Locations tab
4. Change the Command Line Tools version to Xcode 6.0
5. Uninstall cocoapods
       $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
   6   Install xcodeproj
       $ sudo gem install xcodeproj
6. Install cocoapods
       $ sudo gem install cocoapods
7. Run pod --version to verify that it worked